# Bubble Chart Data Visualization in imPower/Microstrategy ordering incorrectly

Tags: visualization, graphs

Apologies if this isn't the right community for this, I could not find a "data visualization" site so I felt that this was the closest fit.

I'm currently attempting to build a bubble chart visualization to show how a group of individuals has progressed on an online training course. For context, here is the editor menu I have set up:

[image]

Here is the visualization produced:

[image]

The visualization is correctly sizing bubbles by % completed (and the data is accurate) and is correctly splitting and coloring by E-mail. The problem is that it is **not** correctly ordering horizontally by % completed. Even though the X axis is % Completed, bubbles are being ordered alphabetically by E-mail.

Neither I nor my colleagues have any idea why this is happening. It's been an issue for the past 2 days, and I'm out of ideas.